# Javascript: Declare variables from RegEx, write to cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, cookies

This question has two parts.

First, I need to isolate two strings of text inside a span with the class "test01". Here is what the span looks like:

```
<span class="test01">
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody><tr><td>
<div id="ctl00_ctl07_pnTopBar">
        <a href="/Member/MyHome.aspx">My Account</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/faqs.html">Help</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/Cart.aspx">Cart</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/contact.html">Contact Us</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="/disclaimer.html">Disclaimer</a>
</div>
</td>
    </tr><tr>
<td align="right">
        email@address.com (UserId: 123456) 
        <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$ctl07$EasyLoginView1$lv$EasyLoginStatus$ctl00','')" id="ctl00_ctl07_EasyLoginView1_lv_EasyLoginStatus">Logout</a>
</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
</span>
```

How would I go about isolating the email address, and the ID number (which is not always six digits long), and declare them as variables 'email' and 'uid' ?

Part two- I am also wondering how one would use javascript to write each of these variables to respective cookies.

Comment: Will the email/id be in a specific td always or this too can change?

Comment: RegEx is not the right tool for the job. This could be done very easily and very efficiently using a javascript library like jQuery, if that's an option for you.

Comment: Panwar, this will always be in the same td.

Henry, I am currently using JQuery for other things on the site. If you have a more efficient solution to share, go right ahead :)

Comment: You should'n put block tag inside inline tag use div insted of span.

Comment: added jQuery tag because you said it is allright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a jQuery solution.

When creating this function, I was assuming the following:

- The needed data is always in the last TD (can be easily modified though, easiest would be to add an ID to the TD).
- The userID stuff is always inside parentheses.
- The userID only consists of numbers.

It basically gets the text of the TD, splits it based on the parentheses, the first one will be the email, the numbers in the second one will be the userID.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var cucc=$('.test01 td:last').text();
    var temb=cucc.split(/\(|\)/);
    var email=$.trim(temb[0]);
    var uid=temb[1].replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
});
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/mHqZS/1/)

To set cookies with jQuery, please see this [article about the Cookie Plugin](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-cookies/).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in two teps. First search for:

```
<span class="test01">(.*?)</span>
```

Then you iterate thru the matches with:

```
([a-z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@([a-z0-9_-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,4}) \(UserId: ([0-9]+)
```

The first backreference will contain the *e-mail address* and the third one will have the *id*.

I used all legal character in an e-mail address, in real life it's extremely rare to use smeting like `?` in an address.